# Trying to transfer 5009 rows from csv file to xlsx

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, pandas, xls

```
import pandas as pd    

df1=pd.read_csv('out.csv')
df2=pd.read_excel('file.xls')

df2['Location']=df1['Location']
df2['Sublocation']=df1['Sublocation']
df2['Zone']=df1['Zone']
df2['Subnet Type']=df1['Subnet Type']
df2['Description']=df1['Description']

newfile = input("Enter a name for the combined xlsx file: ")
print('Saving to new xlsx file...')
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(newfile)
df2.to_excel(writer, index=False)
writer.save()
```

Basically, it reads a csv file with 5 columns and it reads a xls file with existing columns, then makes a xlsx file where the two files are combined with the 5 new columns.

So it works, but only for 4999 rows, the last 10 dont have the 5 new columns in the new xlsx file.

Comment: This problem isn't expressed very clearly. But your comments elsewhere suggest that the CSV and XLS have the same number of rows, and you just want the columns in the CSV to show up next to the columns in the XLS. So (for example) if your XLS has 10 columns and your CSV has 5 columns, you would like the values in the XLS to eventually wind up in columns A through J (in the final XLSX), and the values in the CSV to wind up in columns K through O?

Comment: I am not a `pandas` user, but this can be accomplished in a relatively straightforward manner by using lower-level packages directly. You'd want `csv` from the standard library, `xlrd` (to read the .xls), and `xlsxwriter` (to write the .xlsx). Most likely those are already installed, because they are used by `pandas`, but it is also simple to install them separately if needed.

Comment: @john-y I'll give the separate modules a try. As to your first comment, yes exactly. XLS values A-P and values in CSV to wind up in Q-U of XLSX. so my XLS has 16 columns and CSV has 5.

Comment: @john-y I'm kind of struggling with how to write the xlsx file after reading both csv and xls. I am actually already reading the xls file in the bgeinning of the program to grab some data to use in a dict. So it's defined as xlsfile and used like this `xlsfile = input("Enter filepath to xls file or xls filename if in working directory: ")
print('Reading xls...')
book = xlrd.open_workbook(xlsfile, on_demand=True)` and i also have `target = open('out.csv')` for writing the csv file with the output, the 5 columns.

Comment: I'm sorry no one has provided a full answer on how to do it in `pandas` (the answers from @Shijo seem to only be partly usable), because if you can do it with `pandas`, I'm sure it will be simpler than using the separate individual packages. Yes, I said using the individual packages would be "relatively straightforward", and I still believe that, but you do have to think at a lower, more nitty-gritty level than how you think when you use `pandas`. I will try to post an answer when I have more time (if no one solves it in `pandas` first).

Comment: Thanks! I'll keep trying with the indivdual packages. As far as I know, my original code with pandas is the most efficient way to do this, but it doesn't work for the last 10 rows. I say efficient because append() doesn't seem to work right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am little confused about the problem, so i came up with 2 options 
1. append df1 to df2
2. Merge df1 to df2 (adds new columns to existing df)
. I think in your case you dont have same number of rows in csv and excel and for that reason last 10 rows dont have value in the output

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.array([
    ['a', 51, 61],
    ['b', 52, 62],
    ['c', 53, 63]]),
    columns=['name', 'attr11', 'attr12'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.array([
    ['a', 31, 41],
    ['b', 32, 42],
    ['c', 33, 43],
    ['d',34,44]]),
    columns=['name', 'attr21', 'attr22'])

df3= df1.append(df2)
print df3
print pd.merge(df1,df2,on='name',how='right')
```

Comment: Both the csv and xls have 5009 rows. But my code is stopping at 4999 rows for some reason. Basically its reading a csv and xls then combining them in to a new xlsx file with the csv columns added, after the xls columns

Comment: This answer turns out to be right, even including the diagnosis that your CSV isn't what you expected. Besides `merge`, you could also use `concat` with `axis=1`.

Comment: @john-y I don't really understand the array part of this code

Comment: @DaVinci: The arrays are just there to set up some sample data. The whole "answer" is really in the last line. (I jumped the gun when I said this answer is "right" because that `df3` stuff is just extra fluff, left over from not fully understanding what you want, and not serving any purpose. It really should be removed from the answer. I should have said this answer *contains* a solution, because of the `merge`.)

Comment: `df3 = pd.concat(df1,df2,axis=1)` gives me a `TypeError: concat() got multiple values for argument 'axis'`

Answer (score 1):

Most likely there is a way to do what you want within `pandas`, but in case there isn't, you can use lower-level packages to accomplish your task.

To read the CSV file, use the `csv` module that comes with Python. The following code loads all the data into a Python list, where each element of the list is a row in the CSV. Note that this code is not as compact as an experienced Python programmer would write. I've tried to strike a balance between being readable for Python beginners and being "idiomatic":

```
import csv

with open('input1.csv', 'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    csvdata = []
    for row in reader:
        csvdata.append(row)
```

To read the .xls file, use [`xlrd`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/xlrd), which should already be installed since `pandas` uses it, but you can install it separately if needed. Again, the following code is not the shortest possible, but is hopefully easy to understand:

```
import xlrd

wb = xlrd.open_workbook('input2.xls')
ws = wb.sheet_by_index(0)  # use the first sheet
xlsdata = []
for rx in range(ws.nrows):
    xlsdata.append(ws.row_values(rx))
```

Finally, write out the combined data to a .xlsx file using [XlsxWriter](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/XlsxWriter). This is another package that may already be installed if you've used `pandas` to write Excel files, but can be installed separately if needed. Once again, I've tried to stick to relatively simple language features. For example, I've avoided `zip()`, whose workings might not be obvious to Python beginners:

```
import xlsxwriter

wb = xlsxwriter.Workbook('output.xlsx')
ws = wb.add_worksheet()
assert len(csvdata) == len(xlsdata)  # we expect the same number of rows
for rx in range(len(csvdata)):
    ws.write_row(rx, 0, xlsdata[rx])
    ws.write_row(rx, len(xlsdata[rx]), csvdata[rx])
wb.close()
```

Note that `write_row()` lets you choose the destination cell of the leftmost data element. So I've used it twice for each row: once to write the .xls data at the far left, and once more to write the CSV data with a suitable offset.

Comment: Strange, I'm getting an AssertionError. I don't understand that, both files have 5009 rows... This exception shouldn't be coming up. @john-y

Comment: Well, poke around. Use print statements to see what the lengths *really* are. Maybe one of them has a row of headings and the other doesn't?

Comment: Wow, that the heck? printed len for each data. csv has 5000 and xls has 5009. Maybe i need to define a header row for csv or both?

Comment: OK, so the source of the problem is definitely your CSV. The behavior you observed (for your own attempt and @Shijo's `merge` suggestion) is completely down to your CSV not having the number of rows you expected. How did you come to the conclusion that your CSV had 5009 rows? (Not saying you did anything wrong, just trying to figure out where things diverged from expectations.)

Comment: I'm just looking at the csv in excel for how many rows it has

Comment: OK, so Excel is telling you the CSV has 5009 rows? Python's `csv` module says there are only 5000. I would guess that there is some kind of unusual data that is confusing Python's CSV parser. Maybe unexpected quotation marks. You could pinpoint where the problem is by printing out the length of each of the CSV rows in Python, to see if any are **not** 5. If you just need a quick workaround, then use Excel to save the CSV as a workbook, and use `xlrd` to read it (it will read either .xls or .xlsx).

Comment: I'll give that a try... Yeah the csv has like 17 cells with quotation marks in them.

Comment: Quotation marks can be fine, but if they are not "escaped" properly, Excel may handle them differently than Python's `csv` module. The point being, some of the end-of-line markers may be interpreted as being part of your data instead of marking the end of a row.

Comment: So, interesting. Seem when i convert out.csv to xls using pandas, it shows length as 5000 but when i save it manually as a xls both xls file have the same length and combining them merges both without missing rows! @john-y

Comment: When you convert your .csv to .xls using pandas, of course it is going to use Python, and therefore it will use Python's `csv` module. So it should get the same result as you did when you used Python's `csv` module, and it did. I told you that would be different than using Excel. You got 5009 rows in Excel, so if you save using Excel, of course the resulting workbook will have 5009 rows. That is why I told you to use Excel.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should append data

```
import pandas as pd    

df1=pd.read_csv('out.csv')
df2=pd.read_excel('file.xls')

df2.append(df1)

newfile = input("Enter a name for the combined xlsx file: ")
print('Saving to new xlsx file...')
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(newfile)
df2.to_excel(writer, index=False)
writer.save()
```

Comment: hmmm that actually didn't even append the 5 columns to the xlsx. Column positions in the csv are not the same to the xls. xls ends at P and csv is from A-E.

Comment: `.append()` returns a new object so that would have to be assigned back to `df2`...

Comment: Something like: `df2 = df2.append(df1)`

Comment: could i use `df3 = df2.append(df1)` and change `df2.to_excel` to `df3.to_excel` ? Edit: df2=df2.append(df1) doesn't work and df3 doesn't either

Comment: @Shijo Any way to append starting from a certain column? it keeps appending before the existing columns in the xls

Comment: `append` is not really the right tool to use (once you understand what OP is trying to do!), but you *could* still use it if you transpose the data first, then append, then transpose it back. The right tool is either `merge` (as in your other answer) or `concat`.